# Issues linking boost libraries with Xcode 6.1.1 on Yosemite mac

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I'm using Yosemite and latest version of Xcode.

I've followed the instructions on the Boost website (for UNIX variants), I've tried brew install. I've tried a gist from github.

I've spent a huge amount of time trying to find information about the installation and the XCode set up, yet have not been able to get the libraries to link.

I've tried absolute paths, moving the boost folders around. <> and "" around my include statements. I have made sure command line tools are installed.

I ran the bootstrap.sh script, then invoked b2. Boost is saved in usr/local

I want to use sockets to pass data between to programmes on the same system, implementing something along these line: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/local/stream_server.cpp

Using the code as is, I'm getting errors that Xcode can't find the hpp files and I've tried replacing the <> with "", as per one of the error messages, the other being that it can't locate the files.

Below are screenshots showing what I have done to try and configure Xcode. Perhaps I have not linked in the correct places in Xcode, or perhaps I have linked to the wrong places?

[image: link with libraries]

[image: library search paths]

[image: location of boost]

Comment: I'm sure you've also spent a huge amount of time reposting the exact same question you posted *[15 hours (or 10 hours with the screenshots) ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28980359/revisions)*. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but it doesn't look good.

Comment: I voted to undelete that. Consider setting a bounty or getting someone to help you on-site.

Comment: But is anyone going to answer my question now that it has been voted down. Instead I took the advice and reformatted as it was not my intention to offend and upset people, I need some help. The constructive criticism to my question was helpful and I'm grateful. But at the same time, if that prevents from getting an answer. Am i not allowed to write a well constructed new question. It doesn't seem very fair

Comment: Huh. Why do you think voting exists? Surely it isn't so that people can just recreate the question. For the record, I didn't downvote the question. I just edited the useless ranty bits out, as you remember. It was a still a poor question (if you can't figure out your include paths, how can we?). I voted-to-close for that reason. This question is no better, and I _did_ downvote this for the reason I mentioned: it looks pretty bad you try to artificially generate interest for your question. Again, **[bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)** are for that

Comment: sorry I hadn't heard of bounties

Comment: Now you do. Not that you needed more than common sense to tell that reposting is iffy practice. You may undelete the old one. Perhaps I can favour you with an upvote just for your learning efforts :) (regardless, there are already 2 community undelete votes by now)

Comment: I will do. I have answered my own question above, as I seem to have solved it and there wasn't enough space in a comment to write, so hopefully that is not something else I'm doing wrong!
I will defo use bounties and be more careful about composing questions in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: Answering your own question is ok. I had already upvoted it :)

Comment: he he. I need one more vote to undelete. All good, it's just a couple of votes right. Don't worry

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed it. After trying installs with homebrew, macports and manually (and then deleted all the files everywhere in usr/local between these installs), but it was hard to find everything that needed changing in the backend of Xcode, which I admit to still finding a little confusing at times.

So Header search paths still contained the homebrew cellar as part of the long pathname, so I changed this bit /usr/include User Header Path.
User Search Paths I had as /usr/local/lib according to some instructions I'd found searching for a solution. I've now changed it to /usr/local/lib

After these changes, my errors have finally disappeared! Fingers crossed I've got it right now